# Spectroscopy bimodal fitting isn't giving accurate x data(Wavelength) although y fitting is good. In python 3.7

Tags: python, curve-fitting, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression

I'm trying to fit some bimodal curve using James Phillips's(https://stackoverflow.com/users/2436862/james-phillips) RamanSpectroscopy (https://bitbucket.org/zunzuncode/ramanspectroscopyfit/src/master/) It fits y data(intensity amplitude) perfectly but returning exact x data for all the files which I was expecting to shift more or less. I tried lmfit models but doesn't fit my data well. This raman equation fits them as expected just doesn't really get the x axis right. I'm getting x axis with peakutils.  Can I tweak some parameters in the ramanspectroscopy function to get accurate x readings?

Here's my code

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import warnings
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
from numpy import genfromtxt
from peakutils.plot import plot as pplot
import peakutils


def get_peak(xData,yData):
    # bounds on parameters are set in generate_Initial_Parameters() below
    def double_Lorentz(x, a, b, A, w, x_0, A1, w1, x_01):
        return a * x + b + (2 * A / np.pi) * (w / (4 * (x - x_0) ** 2 + w ** 2)) + (2 * A1 / 
                 np.pi) * ( w1 / (4 * (x - x_01) ** 2 + w1 ** 2))

    # function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
    # bounds on parameters are set in generate_Initial_Parameters() below
    def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
        warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")  # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
        return np.sum((yData - double_Lorentz(xData, *parameterTuple)) ** 2)

    def generate_Initial_Parameters():
        # min and max used for bounds
        maxX = max(xData)
        minX = min(xData)
        maxY = max(yData)
        minY = min(yData)

        parameterBounds = []
        parameterBounds.append([-1.0, 1.0])  # parameter bounds for a
        parameterBounds.append([maxY / -2.0, maxY / 2.0])  # parameter bounds for b
        parameterBounds.append([0.0, maxY * 60.0])  # parameter bounds for A
        parameterBounds.append([0.0, maxY / 2.0])  # parameter bounds for w
        parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX])  # parameter bounds for x_0
        parameterBounds.append([0.0, maxY * 60.0])  # parameter bounds for A1
        parameterBounds.append([0.0, maxY / 2.0])  # parameter bounds for w1
        parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX])  # parameter bounds for x_01

        # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
        result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
        return result.x



    # generate initial parameter values
    initialParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

    # curve fit the test data
    fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(double_Lorentz, xData, yData, initialParameters)

    # create values for display of fitted peak function
    a, b, A, w, x_0, A1, w1, x_01 = fittedParameters
    y_fit = double_Lorentz(xData, a, b, A, w, x_0, A1, w1, x_01)
    index = peakutils.peak.indexes(y_fit, thres=0.5, min_dist=100)
    index = index[:1]
    print("X index:", xData[index], "Y index:", y_fit[index])


    print(fittedParameters)
    return xData[index]
```

Comment: it is very hard to follow what you are trying to do.  Half the code appears to try to automate the use of differerntial_evolution to guess initial values.  Is this important? Is that part working correctly? Also: Is the plot you show related in any way? Should we know what any of the traces mean?  Why didn't you print out *any* fit results?   I strongly suggest you simplify to one dataset, get rid of the junk using differential_evolution, and just guess some values based on looking at your data.  Start simple, then build up automation and complexity.

Comment: Yeah sorry about the horrible representation. It's hard to explain if I write it all down or it'll take a long time to do. I'll make a screenrecord video explaining it and put a link here. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I doubt you will get help if you add a screencast.   If your code it hard for you to explain, why do you expect someone could help you?   For sure, if you cannot answer the questions in my previous comment, you won't get further help. This forum is for problems with  **CODE**.  So, simplify your code so that it shows the problem you are having.   Remove unrelated code and graphics.